# What does つっこむ べき mean?

Tags: verbs

I know that べき means should, so what's つっこむ? And what's its infinitive?

Comment: Um, べき goes after the infinitive anyway.

Comment: Have you tried to look it up?

Comment: It is incorrect to call the dictionary form of a Japanese verb "the infinitive".  In Japanese, the dictionary form is finite, and if any form is to be called the infinitive, it should be the 連用形.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

つっこむ is a simple verb which has several meanings including "to plunge", "to retort", "to cram". So つっこむべき means "[You] should cram", "[I] should plunge", or whatever that corresponds to the dictionary definition.

That said, when people suddenly say つっこむべき in a conversation, it's likely to mean "[I/You/etc should] retort / react / butt in / point out someone's error" usually with some comedic nuance. つっこむ is recognized as a role of comedians. See: [What does “tsukkomi” mean?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/6787/5094)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a simple verb, it's a compound verb, a construct which is very common in Japanese.

突{つ}く - to thrust, hit, strike, ...

込{こ}む - to enter/become packed ...

Combining the verbs then gives a verb which means more like "plunge *into*" or "thrust something *into*"

込む is a common suffix in these combined verbs, such as 入れ込む (put something inside) and 飲み込む (to swallow, or more abstractly as "to take in", "to understand").

As for the conjugation, it works the same as 込む when it's written by itself. The "infinitive" is thus what you have already written, 突っ込む.