# is the use of 突っ込まないで considered rude?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-choice, words, verbs

[image]

> ごめん。深く突っ込まないで

In this context and in general, I wonder is the meaning more like "please don't be noisy and leave it", or "haha, it's nothing to worry about!"?

The use of ごめん before that phrase makes me more confused, as if the character is trying to soften the rude answer, like "don't be offended, but it's none of your business"

Could someone please explain this difference to me?

To add more context: the character with long hair thinks that drinking beer is strange cause they all are supposed to be middle-schoolers (the pigtail girl is actually a vampire, so she's "mature enough")

Comment: Welcome to the Japanese SE. I loved the manga and the anime, and the opening and ending themes in anime were great as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is

> is the use of 突っ込まないで considered rude?

so the answer is, **no it's not rude**.

---

> I wonder is the meaning more like "please don't be noisy and leave it", or "haha, it's nothing to worry about!"?

It would be the latter. For your specific example it's "haha **sorry**". Pigtail girl is apologizing for the fact the long-haired girl was puzzled. Hope this explains the ごめん you were confused about.

It's similar to saying "sorry about that, yes I know what you're thinking, but it's a long story".

If I wanted to sound rude - e.g. "it's none of your business" - I could say:

- ほっとけ leave me alone
- だから何？ so what?
- 口出しするな don't tell me
- 文句ある? you have a problem with me?

---

**Edit: I added this edit because there's a caveat regarding ごめん. Note that this would not apply to the example manga provided in your question.**

Even **if** the sentence was meant to be rude or hostile, it still would totally make sense to prepend or append ごめん. So "ごめん, fuck you" would work. In such case, the ごめん (as in excuse me or sorry) would be added for sarcasm, courtesy, etc., - it's up to the context really. I believe this isn't a Japanese-only thing tho.

Comment: Definitely isn’t just a Japanese thing (regarding the edit). Perfectly normal also in English to say things like, “Sorry, but fuck you”.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing rude examples too!! It's so interesting for me to learn more about spoken language!

Answer (score 5):

For 突っ込む in 突っ込まないで, see for example

- [Trying to understand ツッコミ and 突っ込まない and similiar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/101823/45489)
- [What does つっこむ べき mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44641/45489)

It is basically 'making corrections to ぼけ (something ridiculous)' in a comedy talk.

So, it is fine to understand 深く突っ込まないで as 'leave it', but literally it is like "don't go details into (my having beer)".

In the particular context, understanding ごめん as softening "don't" is ok, too. Or maybe like "excuse me (I can't explain OR I ask you to leave it)".

In terms of meaning, the whole phrase means like *never mind*.

Comment: I've read the manga. I would say in this particular context her ごめん is the second case, as in "I'm sorry that I'm not gonna explain it but (...)"

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If said in a conversation, would it be considered rude? Or playful?

Comment: @ChestershireLiddell By itself, no. Because 突っ込まないで is an imperative, it can sound strong or rude depending on the tone, though.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this question arose from interpreting 突っ込む as a verb with a negative or offensive connotation. However, 突っ込む does not carry a negative meaning like "be noisy" or "make a fuss". In this context, 突っ込む just means "to point out or ask about something strange", as seen in [the 3rd and 4th definitions here](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%AA%81%E3%81%A3%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80). This verb is widely used not only in comedic contexts but also in serious academic discussions. It's common to hear people say 突っ込みをお待ちしております ("I'm looking forward to your corrections").

Of course, pointing something out too strongly and harshly can be rude, but the remark made by this long-haired woman is just "Beer? Why?", which is not rude at all. Conversely, politely asking not to do so is not considered rude either.

> ごめん、深く突っ込まないで…。
> (It's natural that you're curious but) sorry, please don't ask / delve into this...